# Threading/Multiprocessing in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-multithreading

I have the following code:

```
import SimpleHTTPServer
import SocketServer

def http_server():
    PORT = 80
    Handler = SimpleHTTPServer.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler
    httpd = SocketServer.TCPServer(("", PORT), Handler)
    httpd.serve_forever()
```

The problem with this is that, because of `httpd.serve_forever()`, it hangs the rest of the program. I'm assuming I could use threading to run this on its own thread, so the rest of the program can execute independently of the server, but I'm not sure how to implement this.

Comment: Your imports should be at module level, not inside of the function

Comment: @RyanHaining Yes, that's something I didn't catch when copy/pasting code around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplest way, straight from the [docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html):

```
from threading import Thread

t = Thread(target=http_server)
t.start()
```

Note that this thread will be difficult to kill as-is, KeyboardInterrupts do not propagate to random threads that you've `start()`ed.  You may want to set `daemon=True` or have some more sophisticated method to shut it down.